# Efeito css ao clicar com mouse

Tags: html5, css3

Tenho um um efeito css em uma div utilizando a propriedade hover , gostaria de saber se é possível ativar esse efeito somente quando for clicada .

```
<div class="original">
<div class="spin">
<div class="box">Texto</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
color: #fff;
margin: 30px;
}

.original {
background: #d2d2d2;
margin: 10px 15px;
width: 95px;
}

.box {
background: red;
height: 95px;
width: 95px;
line-height: 95px;
text-align: center;
transform: rotate(-55deg);

  }
 .spin {
  cursor: pointer;
  }
 .spin:hover {
   animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
 }

  @keyframes spin {
  0% {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
   100% {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
   }
   }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Daria para tentar usar o seletor `:target` para elementos com IDs combinado com a HASH da URL, por exemplo:

```
.spin:target {
     animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}
```

O código deve ser algo como:

> Clica no abaixo no botão <kbd>executar</kbd> e depois no link <kbd>página toda</kbd>

```css
body {
     color: #fff;
     margin: 30px;
}

.original {
     background: #d2d2d2;
     margin: 10px 15px;
     width: 95px;
}

.box {
     background: red;
     height: 95px;
     width: 95px;
     line-height: 95px;
     text-align: center;
     display: block;
     transform: rotate(-55deg);
}

.spin {
     cursor: pointer;
}

.spin:target {
     animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
         transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
         transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="original">

    <div class="spin" id="elemento1">
        <a class="box" href="#elemento1">Texto</a>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="original">

    <div class="spin" id="elemento2">
        <a class="box" href="#elemento2">Texto</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Mas ai complica, porque depende do hash na url para animar, como:

```
http://site.com/pagina.html#elemento1
http://site.com/pagina.html#elemento2
```

Então se o hash for mais um problema do que solução para ti, somente usando javascript em com uma classe para isto. No CSS deve ficar assim:

```
.spin.animar {
     animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}
```

O código todo pode ser algo como (leia os comentários para entender o código):

```js
//Detecta quando a página já foi carregada (menos os recursos externos)
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

    //Pega todos elementos com a classe spin
    var els = document.querySelectorAll('.spin');
    
    //Itera todos elementos
    for (var i = els.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {

        //Aplica o evento onclick
        els[i].onclick = animarElement;
    }
});

function animarElement()
{
    var els = document.querySelectorAll('.spin');

    for (var i = els.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        var el = els[i];

        //Remove a classe CSS animar de todos elementos, menos o elemento clicado (se já tiver a classe nele)
        if (el !== this && el.classList.contains('animar')) {
            el.classList.remove('animar');
        }
    }
    
    //Se o elemento clicado não tiver a classe animar ainda então aplicamos ela
    if (!this.classList.contains('animar')) {
        this.classList.add('animar');
    }
}
```

```css
body {
     color: #fff;
     margin: 30px;
}

.original {
     background: #d2d2d2;
     margin: 10px 15px;
     width: 95px;
}

.box {
     background: red;
     height: 95px;
     width: 95px;
     line-height: 95px;
     text-align: center;
     display: block;
     transform: rotate(-55deg);
}

.spin {
     cursor: pointer;
}

.spin.animar {
     animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% {
         transform: rotateY(0deg);
    }
    100% {
         transform: rotateY(360deg);
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="original">

    <div class="spin">
        <div class="box">Texto</div>
    </div>

</div>

<div class="original">

    <div class="spin">
        <div class="box">Texto</div>
    </div>

</div>
```

---

Note que o uso de `:active`, `:focus` e outros semelhantes só funcionam com elementos *"clicáveis"* ou *"focáveis"*, DIVs não irão suportar isto, logo fazer isto:

```
.spin:active {
    animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}
```

Para elementos DIVs não irá funcionar.

Segue alguns exemplos deles são os elementos que suportam o `:active`:

- `<a href=""></a>` (deve conter o atributo `href=`)
- `<button></button>`
- E aos elementos associados a um `<label></label>`

Answer (score 0):

Daria para fazer tb usando `radio-button`, vc pode colocar um `input:radio` que quando :checked vao rotacionar o `.spin`. Mas para isso vc precisa transformar o elemento `div.spin` em uma `label.spin` como um `for=""` para o `ID` do `radio-button`, parece complicado, mas não é como vc pode ver no código.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body {
 color: #fff;
 margin: 30px;
}

.original {
 background: #d2d2d2;
 margin: 10px 15px;
 width: 95px;
}

.box {
 background: red;
 height: 95px;
 width: 95px;
 line-height: 95px;
 text-align: center;
 transform: rotate(-55deg);
 display: block;
}

.spin {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
}

@keyframes spin {
 0% {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
 }

 100% {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
 }
}
[id^="btn"]:checked + .spin {
 animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}
[id^="btn"] {
 display: none; 
}
```

```html
<div class="original">
 <input type="radio" name="btns" id="btn1">
 <label for="btn1" class="spin">
  <span class="box">Texto</span>
 </label>
</div>
<div class="original">
 <input type="radio" name="btns" id="btn2">
 <label for="btn2" class="spin">
  <span class="box">Texto</span>
 </label>
</div>
```

---

**Para ativar individualmente**

Se vc quiser que o usuário possa marcar e desmarcar o elemento basta trocar o `input` de `type="radio"` para `type="checkbox"`. Ai ele pode ativar e desativar o .spin individualmente.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```css
body {
 color: #fff;
 margin: 30px;
}

.original {
 background: #d2d2d2;
 margin: 10px 15px;
 width: 95px;
}

.box {
 background: red;
 height: 95px;
 width: 95px;
 line-height: 95px;
 text-align: center;
 transform: rotate(-55deg);
 display: block;
}

.spin {
 cursor: pointer;
 display: block;
}

@keyframes spin {
 0% {
  transform: rotateY(0deg);
 }

 100% {
  transform: rotateY(360deg);
 }
}
[id^="btn"]:checked + .spin {
 animation: spin 3s linear infinite;
}
[id^="btn"] {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="original">
 <input type="checkbox" id="btn1">
 <label for="btn1" class="spin">
  <span class="box">Texto</span>
 </label>
</div>
<div class="original">
 <input type="checkbox" id="btn2">
 <label for="btn2" class="spin">
  <span class="box">Texto</span>
 </label>
</div>
```