# Como faço o quadrado girar quando clicar no botão? JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
<title>Cubo Gira</title>
<style>
    body {
        background-color: beige;
    }
    #cubo {
        margin: auto;
        margin-top: 200px;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        background-color: red;

    }
    #btn {
        margin: auto;
        margin-left: 125px;
        margin-top: 125px;
        width: 50px;
        height: 25px;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div id="cubo">
    <input type="button" value="Girar" onclick="giro()" id="btn">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Eu queria usar function no Script do código pra adicionar o evento de transform: rotate() ao quadrado quando o botão for clicado.

Porém não consigo usando document.getElementById("").style.transform = rotate();

A dúvida, no geral, é: como consigo por duas funções nesse botão. 1° Função: Girar o quadrado em -45deg e 2° Função: Girar o quadrado em 45deg (voltar a posição inicial).

Comment: `rotate()` não é uma função do JS, mas você pode aciona-la no `style` como uma string que ela será interpretada pelo motor do CSS, dessa forma: `document.getElementById("cubo").style.transform = "rotate(-45deg)"`

Answer (score 2):

vc pode fazer uma classe, que chama uma keyframe (css) responsavel por girar até 50% 45 graus e, depois, no 100% voltar pra 0 graus. quando clicar em giro, vc adiciona a classe css.
https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/rotate
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes

Mais ou menos assim:

```
.girar {
  animation: girar 2s infinite linear;
}
@keyframes girar {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
  50% {
    transform: rotate(45deg)
  }
  100%{
    transform: rotate(0deg)
  }
}

function giro() {
  var cubo = document.getElementById('cubo') 
  cubo.classList.add('girar')
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Cara a forma mais fácil de fazer isso é criando uma classe no CSS chamado por exemplo `.giro` e com o JS vc faz um `toggle` dessa classe quando o elemento for clicado. Para entender melhor veja o código abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```js
function giro() {
   document.getElementById("cubo").classList.toggle('giro');
//o toggle vai adicionar e remover a classe a cada clique
}
```

```css
body {
    background-color: beige;
}
#cubo {
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 200px;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: red;

}
#btn {
    margin: auto;
    margin-left: 125px;
    margin-top: 125px;
    width: 50px;
    height: 25px;
}

/* classe que sera feita o toggle */
.giro {
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="cubo">
    <input type="button" value="Girar" onclick="giro()" id="btn">
</div>
```

**OBS:** Se quiser algo similar, mas feito unicamente com CSS veja aqui https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/387486/97477

Answer (score -2):

Galera o isso é gambiarra! Ficaria assim:

```
Var Rotate = 90; 
Var img = document.getElementById("img");
//90 graus

Img.style.transform = "rotate("+rotate+"deg)";
```